# Question about String.Format to display time

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to display time (from a stopwatch and timer) like so:

```
btnButton1.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00}", timespan1.Hours, timespan1.Minutes, timespan1.Seconds)
btnButton2.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}:{2:00}", timespan2.Hours, timespan2.Minutes, timespan2.Seconds)
```

Could anyone please tell me how I can change the formatting of the time like so:

Button1: 0:00 where the first 0 is minute and the second 00 are seconds.

Button2: 000:00 where the first 000 are minutes and the second 00 are seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. Please provide an example of the timespan value and your desired formatted version(s) of it.

Comment: This is an odd format, since you won’t be able to tell the difference between 11 hours 1 minute and 1 hour 11 minutes... Also, have you tried just using `timespan1.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.TimeSpan.TotalMinutes);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a `Double` type, you need to *present* it as an `Integer`.
There's a catch, in that the `Integer` conversion rounds up the middle point (`90.5`, `90` minutes and `30` seconds, will convert to `91`, so you'ld end up with `91:30`).
Use instead [`Math.Truncate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.truncate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Math.Truncate);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to preserve the integral part of the value ([`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Math.Round);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) would round up, too).

```
Dim timespan1 As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(1, 9, 1)
Dim timespan2 As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(3, 3, 30)

btnButton1.Text = String.Format("{0:#0}:{1:00}", Math.Truncate(timespan1.TotalMinutes), timespan1.Seconds)
btnButton2.Text = String.Format("{0:#0}:{1:00}", Math.Truncate(timespan2.TotalMinutes), timespan2.Seconds)
```

```
btnButton1.Text = "69:01"
btnButton2.Text = "183:30"
```

The format could also be  `{0:N0}:{1:00}`

Or, if you don't want to see a leading `0` in the `seconds` part, use `{0:N0}:{1:N0}`, which will give:

```
69:1
183:30
```